# Google Analytics generate test data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm developing a web application where I need to retrieve statistics from Google Analytics. In order to test API results I created a website which has the analytics.js script on every page. But so far I haven't been able to figure out how to generate organic traffic data... from what I understand in order for a visit to count as organic the user has to access my site by clicking a link on a search engine. How can I achieve this? Any suggestions on generating "mock" organic traffic for development purposes?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ga.js you can add search engines via [_addOrganic](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiSearchEngines#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addOrganic). With Universal Analytics you can add search engines in the view configuration.

A search engine to Google ist really nothing more than a referrer with a known url parameter for the search term. So place a form on a domain you control and use it to send a GET parameter to your site; add it as search engine with your parameter and it will show as organic traffic.

Comment: Ok, here is what I did... unfortunately didn't worked. Create a simple html page on my local server with the ga script. Then, with the help of the Firefox refControl plugin changed the referrer to match my-search-engine.com. Same setup in google analytics page, Domain Name: my-search-engine.com, Query Parameter: q. Finally just made a get in the browser to http://localhost?q=results, double checked that the referer is setted correctly to the custom domain... however it is still not recognized as organic source. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if it was my configuration but once I added a domain name into my hosts files 127.0.0.1  mydomain.com , the script started tracking organic traffic correctly.